DPDK bbdev test vector for turbo decoder on acc100
one of the test vectors for turbo decoder in acc100 (dpdk bbdev) is as follows. I understand that the hard output is 40 bits but I do not understand how is the input data interpreted! In other words if we want to give these inputs to Matlab lteTurboDecode how can this be done?
Thanks in advance
op_type =
RTE_BBDEV_OP_TURBO_DEC

input0 =
0x7f007f00, 0x7f817f00, 0x767f8100, 0x817f8100, 0x81008100, 0x7f818100, 0x81817f00, 0x7f818100,
0x86007f00, 0x7f818100, 0x887f8100, 0x81815200, 0x81008100, 0x817f7f00, 0x7f7f8100, 0x9e817f00,
0x7f7f0000, 0xb97f0000, 0xa7810000, 0x7f7f4a7f, 0x7f810000, 0x7f7f7f7f, 0x81720000, 0x40658181,
0x84810000, 0x817f0000, 0x81810000, 0x7f818181, 0x7f810000, 0x81815a81, 0x817f0000, 0x7a867f7b,
0x817f0000, 0x6b7f0000, 0x7f810000, 0x81818181, 0x817f0000, 0x7f7f817f, 0x7f7f0000, 0xab7f4f7f,
0x817f0000, 0x817f6c00, 0x81810000, 0x817f8181, 0x7f810000, 0x81816981, 0x7f7f0000, 0x007f8181

hard_output0 =
0xa7d6732e, 0x61

soft_output0 =
0x7f7f7f7f, 0x81817f7f, 0x7f817f81, 0x817f7f81, 0x81817f81, 0x81817f81, 0x8181817f, 0x7f81817f,
0x7f81817f, 0x7f817f7f, 0x81817f7f, 0x817f8181, 0x81818181, 0x817f7f7f, 0x7f818181, 0x817f817f,
0x81818181, 0x81817f7f, 0x7f817f81, 0x7f81817f, 0x817f7f7f, 0x817f7f7f, 0x7f81817f, 0x817f817f,
0x81817f7f, 0x81817f7f, 0x81817f7f, 0x7f817f7f, 0x817f7f81, 0x7f7f8181, 0x81817f81, 0x817f7f7f,
0x7f7f8181

e =
17280

k =
40

rv_index =
1

iter_min =
4

expected_iter_count =
8

ext_scale =
15

num_maps =
0

code_block_mode =
1

op_flags =
RTE_BBDEV_TURBO_SOFT_OUTPUT, RTE_BBDEV_TURBO_SUBBLOCK_DEINTERLEAVE,
RTE_BBDEV_TURBO_NEG_LLR_1_BIT_IN, RTE_BBDEV_TURBO_NEG_LLR_1_BIT_SOFT_OUT

expected_status =
OK

